# azure sql connection timeout in tedious

Tags: node.js, azure, tedious

```
connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.code === 'ESOCKET') {
      console.log('----- Connection lost removing connection from pool -----');
      // self.pool.destroy(connection);
      connection.close();
      connection = new Connection(config);
    }
  });
```

i have to used above code but i got connection timeout error message..

```
{ [ConnectionError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET]
  message: 'Connection lost - read ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

pls help how to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a long idle connection and which will be shut off. This issue is discussed at Github https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/300 for a long time, and currently seems that there still no result yet.

As a workaround, you can try to use https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool#new-connectionpoolpoolconfig-connectionconfig for building a connection with pool.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add my experience with this issue:

I was randomly getting this issue on a new DB bulk load and couldn't replicate it. I found that by reducing the size of the bulkload from 18k records to about 12k the insertion worked without issue. Couldn't get past the 12k though.

Long story short, I found that apparently one of my records exceeded the capacity of the varchar limit I placed on the db and it was throwing an error. However, that error was never exposed to me until I inserted a record one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the connection out of the connection.on() method. In my case I close the connection after the query call, at the end of my application route. Here is my code:

```html
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    let query;
    query = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
    queryDatabase(query,res);
    connection.close();
});
```

Comment: do you call conn.close inside of a conn.on or outside of it? if you call it outside, won't it call conn.close before conn.on's callback is done?